# Text Is Selected After File Read Into A Textbox

Tags: vb.net, file-io, textbox

So after I run the following code, all my text is highlighted in the textbox.

```
Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader("FilePath")
TextBox1.Text = ioFile.ReadToEnd()
```

Is there a way to not select all the text? BTW, its a multiline textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Select Method to remove the selection.

```
    'Cursor at beginning of text.
    TextBox1.Select(0, 0)

    'Cursor at end of text.
    TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0)
```